# Возвращает int вместо float

Tags: типы-данных, c, функции

Добрый день, есть функция, которая должна возвращать среднее арифметическое элементов массива.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T, typename D>  
T Sredn(T ar[], D size)
{
    float SrA=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) SrA+=ar[i]; 
    SrA=SrA/size;
    cout<<SrA<<endl;
    return SrA;
}
void main()
{
    const int n=5; 
    int ar[n]={3, 2, 13, 4, 5}; 
    cout<<"Average amount: "<<Sredn(ar, n)<<endl; 
}
```

Так вот, в самой функции, выводит верно float 5.4. Далее переменная SrA хранит 5.4, но почему-то передает вместо float - int и уже в главной функции будет значение 5. Почему так происходит и как это победить?

Comment: T Sredn(T ar[], D size)

Это значит, что функция вернет тип, соответствующий типу массива. Массив в int. SrA автоматом скастуется в int.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, забыл что функции нужно задать вещественный тип, и что T - задавало функции целочисленный тип.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, аргумент `size` всегда будет типа `size_t`, потому подстановка D в шаблоне не нужна вообще, это раз.

Также лучше тип возврата захардкодить как `double`, иначе, при выходе из функции вы неявно приводите `SrA` типа `float` к типу массива - T. Если T - это int, то усекается дробная часть, а среднее арифметическое - это всегда вещественное число. Не надо так!